# Check Collision between tags from a 3rd object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, unityscript, scoring

I have run into a bit of an issue while trying to get a scoring system into my game. I have a script on the camera to display the score via a GUI box. I want to check for collision of two other objects and then increment/decrement my score based off of the collision. I have "notes" falling down from the top of the screen and if they go off the bottom and hit the box tagged "miss" then it would decrease the score by some amount.

Script on Camera:

```
#pragma strict

var score: int = 0;
var customSkin : GUISkin;

function OnGUI()
{
    GUI.skin = customSkin;

    //Sets the background color of GUI objects to clear
    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.clear;

    GUI.Box(new Rect(770,25,150,60), "Score: " + score.ToString("0"));
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having? Are you trying to work out how to detect collisions, or how to relay that information to your GUI?

Comment: @AdamH I get home to display the information but not how to detect the collision of two other objects from a third object. So I want the camera to listen for a collision between something tagged note and something tagged miss. That way I can handle all the scoring code within the camera

Answer (score 1):

Create script, attach it to your notes. Inside this script create [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) function and write your code to decrease score. 
For example:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.collider.CompareTag("miss"))
    {
        ScoreManager.Instance.Score -= 10;
    }
}
```

All "notes" and "miss" objects must have Collider component. And one of those (all "notes" or just "miss"-object) must have Rigidbody component.

Helpful link: [Colliders and collisions](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Comment: The question specifically states JS. This is C#. You may want to edit your code example to match this.